# Apache Reverse Proxy - Substitute URL

Tags: reverse-proxy, httpd, apache-2.4, mod-filter

We have an HTTPD server `A` in our network having a private (internal) and a public (accessible from internet) IP. The server acts as a proxy to another server `B`. Some responses from `B` include its hostname as well. I'm using a `SUBSTITUTE` filter to replace all occurrences of `B`'s hostname with `A`'s hostname.

The issue is, that I need to replace with `A`'s public IP if the request came from the internet, and its private IP if the request came from within the network.

How can I do that? Can it even be done?

I'm running HTTPD v2.4.3.

AweSIM

Comment: Simply have a different virtualhost entry with a specific configuration for each unique ip-address....

Comment: I would say you shouldn't use either IP in the redirection. URLs should contain a hostname rather than an IP address.